# Binding Handsontable cells to complex objects

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'm trying to use [Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/index.html) for some basic editing and number formatting.

The data, including formatting info is fetched from the server and would look similar to this:

```
var data = [
    [ { num:'1.1', color:'red' }, { num:'2.2', color:'green' } ],
    [ { num:'3.4', color:'yellow' }, { num:'4.4', color:'blue' } ]
];
```

Now, I would like to pass this data to my `Handsontable` and have each cell display/edit the `.num` values. By using a custom renderer and editor (briefly explained here: [Understanding cell functions](https://github.com/handsontable/jquery-handsontable/wiki/Understanding-cell-functions)), I have found a solution that handles manual editing - see this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7akqc87x/5/

However, there are two problems with this solution:

- Pasting values (e.g. from Excel) doesn't work as intended - the pasted values completely overwrite the bound objects instead of updating their `.num` properties.
- Numeric validation doesn't work - if I add `type: 'numeric'` to the `cellProperties`, the first edited cell won't exit "edit mode", and no more cells can be edited.

Am I on the right track here? If so, how can I fix these two problems? If not, is there an easier (built-in?) way of binding cells to custom objects?

*(I am aware that you can bind an entire row to a custom object - [Object data source](http://handsontable.com/demo/datasources.html#nested) - but I haven't found a solution for individual cells)*

Answer (score 1):

**Custom Cell Rendering:**

In your Hands On Table settings you can add the following to display the num and the color as the background color from your object:

```
renderer: function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
  if(value){
    td.innerHTML = value.num;
    td.style.backgroundColor = value.color;
  }
  return td;
},
```

http://docs.handsontable.com/0.18.0/demo-custom-renderers.html

Sounds like you were able to setup a custom editor, if not you there are instructions here:
http://docs.handsontable.com/0.18.0/tutorial-cell-editor.html

I don't know about pasting from excel with this, at the very least the custom editor would need to take only a single argument.  Only one is going to come from excell anyway.  Perhaps with hooks would be a good method to investigate for that.  Also, probably would want to start by extending the default editor also explained in the above docs rather than a complete custom one.

---

Setting the type to numeric doesn't work as it expects a number not a custom object.  The 'types' predefine a set of renderer, editor and validator as the example they give in the documentation you found:

```
 {
  renderer: Handsontable.NumericRenderer,
  editor: Handsontable.editors.TextEditor,
  validator: Handsontable.NumericValidator
}
```

https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/wiki/Understanding-cell-functions

Comment: Please see the JSFiddle (link in the question). The renderer and editor work as intended. What doesn't work is validation and pasting values.

Comment: @Sphinxxx Check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g5CLwxMGHvdVBGPdU1ed?p=preview)

this is the way i found solution for one of my similar problem.

Comment: @NaushadKM - So basically, for each row you put the custom objects into `.colXX` properties in a temporary "row object", and then you simply let HOT's standard [nested column mapping](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.18.0/tutorial-data-sources.html#page-nested) do the rest of the work? I really like that solution! If you make it an answer, you get the checkmark :)